# Making sure a string only contains numbers, letters, and underscores with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string, validation, preg-match

So, I know I'm going to need a regular expression for this, and to use `preg_match()`.

The [documentation for `preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) says that the function will return either false, or false-ish, if the offset is longer than the string length. I interpreted the documentation to mean that it will return false if there are no matches.

I'm terrible with regular expressions, but after reading about them[on this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) I attempted to write a function that did what I needed. It isn't working.

I have the following snippet:

```
  if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $requested_table_name) === false) {
      echo "Invalid String";
  } else {
      echo "You're golden, Ponyboy";
  }
```

If I understand correctly the backslashes start and end the regular expression, the carat tells the expression to start at the beginning of the string. The character class says match a character that is a lowercase letter, an uppercase letter, a number, or an underscore, then the `+` symbol says to match that character set to the entire string, rather than just the first character of the string.

I must be mistaken because the output of my program says that the string is valid regardless of the input.

Is the problem with my code the use of the `preg_match()` function, or the syntax of my regular expression? In either case what is the problem specifically, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Use anchor: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/`

Comment: Just use `\w+`, `^\w+$` (with anchors to make full string checked). `\w` is alphanumeric characters and underscores. http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html `\w stands for "word character". It always matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: @anubhava That doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: Please provide a sample of what `$requested_table_name` contains.

Comment: @chris85 that returned a syntax error. I'm kind of a boneheaded with regex, so if you could form a complete answer explaining the principles, I would e very appreciative.

Comment: @chris85 It is a `POST` variable from a form

Comment: "the + symbol says to match that character set to the entire string, rather than just the first character of the string." Not quite -- it means match 1 or more of the previous thing. If the plus follows a bracket group, it means match one or more of things from that group.

Comment: Yes, I mean provide us with the content you are running your regex against so we can test it/ reproduce the issue. That might have complained about no delimiters, `/^\w+$/` would be the usage in `preg_match`. Would work the same as `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/` though. We need input.

Comment: @chris85 You're input was what I would be expecting. It's user input, so it could be a variety of things. I just wanted to make sure the string only contained underscores, letters, and numbers. Your solution works correctly.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I appreciate the comment, but I'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: @Allenph For example, `/x+/` means "match one or more x" and `/[0-9]+/` means "match one or more digits." If you want to match the whole string, you have to use anchors. Thus, `/[0-9]+/` means "the string must contain one or more digits anywhere", `/^[0-9]+/` means "the string must contain one or more digits at the start," `/[0-9]+$/` means "the string must contain one or more digits at the end," and `/^[0-9]+$/` means "the whole string must contain only one or more digits."

Comment: Either of the answers below work for you, questions?

Answer (score 5):

Your forward slashes are delimiters. The `^` does say `start of string`. The `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` does list the characters your want to allow, one or more times. However after that one or more times you are allowing anything e.g. `A!` would be valid because it starts with an `A`. If you anchor that expression you will be sure only those characters are allowed.

The `=== false` is incorrect because the return is `0`, or `1`, not `false`.

Demo (of incorrect checking, not answer yet):

```
<?php
$string = 'asdf2341234_';
$return = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $string);
if ($return === false){
    echo 'is false';
} else {
    echo 'not false';
}
var_dump($return);
```

So your regex should be...

```
if (!preg_match('/^\w+$/', $string)) {
    echo "Invalid String" . $string . "\n";
} else {
    echo "You're golden, Ponyboy"  . $string . "\n";
}
```

or...

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/', $string)) {
    echo "Invalid String" . $string . "\n";
} else {
    echo "You're golden, Ponyboy"  . $string . "\n";
}
```

or...

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d_]+$/i', $string)) {
    echo "Invalid String" . $string . "\n";
} else {
    echo "You're golden, Ponyboy"  . $string . "\n";
}
```

You can test regexs on regex101.com. It gives an explanation on everything you are inputting.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path with the regular expression. You're trying to remove any unwanted characters, so look into [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace).

Some of the comments mention the shorthands like `\w` matching a single letter, number, or underscore. There's also `\W` (capital) which matches any single character that is not a letter, number, or underscore.

This will do what you want: `$sanitized_input = preg_replace("/\W/", "", $input);`

Or, without using the shorthand, note the `^` that negates the characters in a `[class]`: `$sanitized_input = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", $input);`

Be sure to check that what `preg_replace` returns is what you want (ie check for `null` on failures).